# Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1 - Clean doesn't work

Tags: android, andengine

I'm trying to export an andengine game that uses GLES2 AnchorCenter and Box2DPhysics add-on. But when trying to export a signed package, I get the above error. I've checked `Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries` and there are 2 `andengine-gles2-anchorcenter.jar` from the same path.
I've tried deleting the whole `Android Dependencies library` and then use `Clean`, but the error is still there.
I've also tried manually deleting the jar from libs folder in the `package explorer`, but it isn't there.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

1. See View -> Problems and look for anything related to your project and fix
2. "and there are 2 andengine-gles2-anchorcenter.jar" - remove any additional entries.

Comment: That is the problem, how do I remove the additional entries?